# Array is not being updated in useState hook?

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-hooks

I have an array of objects like this

```
const array = [
 {
  age: 13,
  name: "Housing"
  },
  {
  age: 23
  name: "Housing"
  }
]
```

I want to use this array to create chart so I need to create two arrays from `names` and `ages`. Then I want to pass it down as props to another component

So far I came up with this in my parent component

```
const [names, setNames] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    createArray();
  }, []);

const createArray = () => {
    if (contentLoading) {
      const newNames= array.map((item) => item.name);
      setNames([...names, newNames]);
    }
  };
```

The problem here is that `newNames` is being created but when I set it with hook `setNames`, `names` is not updated, it is still empty. I'm not sure what am I doing wrong.
All the help will be much appreciated.

Comment: why are you passing `createArray` at the second argument of `useEffect` ? The second parameter should be an array

Comment: typo :), I pass [] in my code

Comment: what is the value of the variable `array` ? It might be empty, that's why your state is not updated

Comment: ```array``` this component getting as prop. When I'm mapping over it it is not empty, ```newNames``` is not empty as a result

Comment: `setNames([...names, ...newNames]);` is the key. How do you verify that the array is still empty, do you use a `console.log` ?

Comment: @OlivierBoissé i use console.log and pass names array as prop to child component and there it is also empty

Comment: are you sure `setNames` is called ? maybe `contentLoading` is falsy and you never update the state

Comment: @OlivierBoissé ```console.log``` inside ```contentLoading``` works, so it gets called

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should have the `useEffect()` subscribe to both the `contentLoading` and `array` props, so it runs whenever there is a change to either, instead of running a single-time after the first mount.

Working code and sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/mutable-mountain-wgjyv

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

const array = [
  {
    age: 13,
    name: "Housing"
  },
  {
    age: 23,
    name: "Housing"
  }
];

const App = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setLoading(true);
    }, 2000);
  }, []);

  return <Child array={array} contentLoading={loading} />;
};

const Child = ({ array, contentLoading }) => {
  const [names, setNames] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    createArray();
  }, [contentLoading, array]);

  const createArray = () => {
    if (contentLoading) {
      const newNames = array.map(item => item.name);
      setNames([...names, ...newNames]);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {names.map(name => (
        <div>{name}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 13):

When updating your state using hooks, it's best to use callbacks.

Try updating your code:

```
setNames(prevNames => [...prevNames, ...newNames])
```

This works in the same way that `prevState` worked with `setSate()`.

On to your solution, you can set the initial state within `useState()`:

```
const array = [
  {
    age: 13,
    name: "Housing"
  },
  {
    age: 23,
    name: "Housing"
  }
];

const [names, setNames] = useState(() => array.map(item => item.name));

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(names);
}, []);
```

Comment: for me in useState my array is still undefined - it passed down as prop

Answer (score 5):

### You should write `setNames([...names, ...newNames]);`

and you missed a comma in the const array after `age: 23`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (contentLoading) {
  setNames( () => {  return [...names, array.map((item) => item.name)] });
}
```